# Ruby on rails Unpermitted parameters: image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm trying to upload an image with paperclip gem,
just now, my models are:

My model

```
class Advert < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attached_file :image
    #accepts_nested_attributes_for :image
end
```

Part of my view:

```
<%= form_for :advert  do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :image %><br>
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

My Controller:

```
def new
        logger.info "Processing the request New..."
        @advert = Advert.new
    end

  def create
        logger.info "Processing the request Create..."
        #logger.info JSON.parse( params[:advert].to_json )
        @advert = Advert.new( advert_params )
        @advert.save
        redirect_to action: "index"
  end

  private
        def advert_params
            params.require(:advert).permit(:title, :features, :description, :areadescription, :rooms, :bathroom, :price, :type, :source, :originaldate, images_attributes: [:image])
        end
```

And the request:

```
Processing by AdministrationController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"VGRNZCT8eo231iT2Fa2Bq2EsG+/4kfkzpgV7NQA4/6o=", "advert"=>{"title"=>"dfas", "features"=>"", "description"=>"", "areadescription"=>"", "rooms"=>"", "bathroom"=>"", "price"=>"", "type"=>"", "source"=>"", "originaldate"=>"", "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fb56fc34c78 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/sv/h26bfj7167jgnb1nm_nstw300000gn/T/RackMultipart20140417-540-iychs8>, @original_filename="i04.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"advert[image]\"; filename=\"i04.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Save Advert"}
Processing the request Create...
Unpermitted parameters: image
```

I have to permit the image and add in the model, what changes I can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you only need to include the attached file `image` in your strong parameters:

```
def advert_params
  params.require(:advert).permit(:title, :features, :description, :areadescription, :rooms, :bathroom, :price, :type, :source, :originaldate, :image)
end
```

The four attributes that Paperclip uses (`image_file_name`, `image_file_size`, `image_content_type` and `image_updated_at`) will be handled automatically when it saves to the database.

Secondly you need to add validation to the image in your model.  Since Paperclip 4.0, at a minimum you must validate the content type of the image, or explicitly state you do not want to.  So in you model you need to add one of the following:

If you want to validate the content type then something like:

```
validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png"]
```

If you want to validate only the file name then something like:

```
validates_attachment_file_name :image, :matches => [/jpe?g\z/, /gif\z/, /png\z/]
```

If you want to explictly not validate the content of the attachment then:

```
do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :image
```

Or you can combine validation using `validates_attachment` if you need to check that the image is present, of a specific type, and no greater than a certain file size for example. For more information, please see the documentation here: `https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip`

Comment: Great! now works! :D I was confused with a little configuration with the version 3 of ror, thanks with your help

Answer (score -1):

remove the image_attributes and just add the :image to the permit hash

Comment: I removed the image_attributes, but display the error:
`Paperclip::Errors::MissingRequiredValidatorError`