# unpermitted parameters when saving paperclip image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I have some troubles with the params or so I think, I already saw [Ruby on rails Unpermitted parameters: image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23137495/ruby-on-rails-unpermitted-parameters-image) and it's no use

I have in my pictures_controller.rb

```rb
def create 
  @picture = Picture.new(picture_params) 
  if @picture.save 
    #ok 
  else 
   #error
  end
end

private
  def picture_params
    params.require(:picture).permit(:project_id, :picture )
  end
```

And in my params

```rb
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "picture"=>{"project_id"=>"10", "picture"=>[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f9e9ccd1378 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20140604-18563-1ce54ta>, @original_filename="apple-touch-icon.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"picture[picture][]\"; filename=\"apple-touch-icon.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">]}}
Unpermitted parameters: picture
```

The param project_id is saved but the fields for paperclip (file  name, file size and file type) are not.

IN model

```rb
has_attached_file :picture, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
validates_attachment_content_type :picture, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png"]
```

And Picture is not a nested attribute, project_id is merely a value I get in a text field so there's no nested model at all, it's a simple form with two fields, project_id and a file field called picture.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it, seems that in my params key picture with the data of the image was an array

```rb
"picture"=>[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f9e9ccd1378 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20140604-18563-1ce54ta>, @original_filename="apple-touch-icon.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"picture[picture][]\"; filename=\"apple-touch-icon.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">]}
```

so I just did a .first to get the value, I think is not the best way of doing this but I'll find a cleaner way of doing it, at least now I know what was the error about

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. So how do you manage when you save multiple images ?